# How to set min(value) variable as 0 when no value is returned by the sql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT min(id) as sid FROM table1 where ....";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$sid = $row['sid'];
```

How can i set $sid as 0, when no value is returned by the sql query

(Here id in the table1 is int type)

Please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no matching rows, the min() function will return a NULL value, so use `coalesce` or `ifnull()` to turn it into a zero:

```
SELECT coalesce(min(id), 0) AS sid ...
SELECT ifnull(min(id), 0) AS sid ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows == 0)
{
 $sid = 0;
}
```

> **mysql_num_rows** return the **number** of rows for a query